# How can I explicitly Deny lambda:InvokeFunction except for trusted resources with IAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

I have been trying to figure out how to create a highly restrictive IAM policy but seem to be running into issues.

We have a lambda that returns sensitive information. A few other lambdas in our system (currently only 3) will need the ability to invoke this handler directly with the `lambda:InvokeFunction` permission but we want to make it very explicit which functions have access.

Our goal is to have an explicit `Deny` IAM policy that whitelists the functions that should be granted access. This way, we can centrally manage the whitelist rather than relying on devs to create `Allow` policies for themselves.

I've tried the following however it seems to block access to everything, including the whitelisted ARN.

```
[
  {
    Effect: 'Allow',
    Action: ['lambda:InvokeFunction'],
    Resource: 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789:function:protected-function',
  },
  {
    Effect: 'Deny',
    Action: ['lambda:InvokeFunction'],
    // the resource we are protecting
    Resource: 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789:function:protected-function',
    Condition: {
      ArnNotLike: {
        // the lambda that should have access to Invoke
        'AWS:SourceArn': ['arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789:function:access-protected-data'],
      },
    },
  }
]
```

What would be the best way to secure this function using IAM to ensure that we can have central management of permissions while still allowing our devs to deploy via a shared CI/CD IAM user that is responsible for provisioning the stack. Open to any ideas that help us secure the function - including protection against any possible internal bad actors/errors.