# resctricting invoking lambda function from another lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

i have 4 simple lambda function lambda A, lambda B, lambda C, lambda D using Node.js
here lambda A invoking lambda C and lambda B invoking D using aws-sdk this is my code

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'ap-south-1';
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
var params = {
    FunctionName: 'lambda C', // the lambda function we are going to invoke
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    LogType: 'Tail',
    Payload: '{ "name" : "Shatya 2" }'
  };

exports.handler = function(event, context) {


lambda.invoke(params,function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      context.fail(err);
    } else {
      context.succeed('Lambda_B said '+ data.Payload);
    }
  })

};
```

Everything is working fine but now I have one more requirement which is related to permission and access invoke deny.

so basically I have to restrict lambda C function to get invoked only by lambda A and same for lambda D means lambda D only can invoked by lambda B.

so if lambda A try to invoke lambda D then it should not get access it should get deny access error same for lambda B if lambda B try to access lambda C

All lambda function in same region and same user.

so basically only specified lambda function can invoked that particular lambda function.

i try to restrict by resource policy but not working.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "lambda:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

this policy I added in lambda D to practice to check deny policy.
here I assumed no lambda function will able to invoke lambda D not even lambda B but its now working all lambda function able to invoke lambda D

Comment: Please add the policy you have been trying with

Comment: i added deny effect for all resources along with all action into lambda D assumed no lambda function can invoke lambda D but all lambda function able to invoke.

Comment: i added policy please check

Comment: BTW it's generally an anti-pattern for one Lambda function to synchronously invoke another Lambda function.

Comment: @jarmod please can you explain a little bit more how to achieve this task

Comment: Actually, it's not clear right now that this is solvable. Related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722007/how-to-restrict-aws-lambda-access-to-only-one-role) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65257791/how-can-i-explicitly-deny-lambdainvokefunction-except-for-trusted-resources-wit), for reference. Would need to dig deeper into this.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the lambda functions cannot invoke other lambda functions without permission, so configure the lambda functions A and B in such a way as to invoke only the lambda functions C and D respectively.

Specify the below-mentioned resource policy explicitly on lambda A

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
   "Resource": [
       "<Replace_With_Lambda_Function_C_ARN>"
   ]
}
```

And, this one on Lambda B

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
   "Resource": [
       "<Replace_With_Lambda_Function_D_ARN>"
   ]
}
```

Comment: I got this thank you but for security purposes I want create permission in lambda C or lambda D